# cloudwatch log to kinesis and s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to use my cloudwatch logs which are basically website access logs.  Need to use these cloudwatch logs for data analytics with kinesis stream since firehose and analytics service is not available in that region. Is there any way to get this done and store analyzed logs on s3 bucket as backup. a